# Casting a set of memory from void* to a class

Tags: c++, memory, pointers, casting, matrix

Okay, so this problem is a little difficult to explain, I'll do my best.

```
void SetData(void* anElement)
{
  myData = anElement;
}
void* GetData()
{
  return myData;
}
```

Basically I have a one-dimensional matrix-class which I made myself that I want to send in as an in-value (anElement) for `SetData()`
which I then later wish to get by calling `GetData()`

This saves the address of the first element in my matrix:

```
SetData(reinterpret_cast<void*>(&myMatrix[0]));
```

the elements in my matrix are all floats, so I thought I would try to ugly-code it like so:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
  myMatrix[i] = reinterpret_cast<float*>(aMessage->GetData())+sizeof(float)*i;
}
```

And the result is that some values seem to come out correct, and others are just bogus.

Awaiting your responses with bated breath =)

Answer (score 2):

```
myMatrix[i] = reinterpret_cast<float*>(aMessage->GetData())+i;
```

is probably what you want here. If you add an integer `i` to a `float*`, the resulting pointer is `i * sizeof(float)` bytes away from the original pointer.